# Only use multer in specific routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, middleware, multer

I am using a middleware as such in my Nodejs app with ReactJS as the frontend:

```
    app.use(*, middleware);
```

The main job of the middleware is to validate the incoming request i.e mainly JWT checking and only then doing a next() to move the request forward to the required route.

The main problem I am having is:

I am using JSON to transfer data back and forth. But as I am uploading a file, I am using FormData() in this specific case. So I have to use multer to read multipart data. The main problem is I have a middleware where every request is going through. So for any file to reach a specific endpoint it has to go through the middleware. So I need to do:

```
    var multer = require('multer');

    var upload = multer({dest: '/upload'});

    app.use("*", upload.any(), middleware);
    app.use("/register", register);
```

Inside middleware:

```
    export const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
      // check if req has proper JWT value. if yes 
      //  next();
      // if no
      // res.json("Sorry can't move on.");
    }
```

The main risk I am facing here is: any malicious user can upload a file to any endpoint. This keeps my API at risk. Is there any way to bypass this and only use multer at an specific endpoint?

Also, if I do:

```
    app.use("*", upload.none(), middleware);
```

I am getting a 500 error. I have no clue where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

app.use("*", middleware ,upload.none());

try to use the middelware function before the upload.none()